# Azure Function don't use Available Hosts Instance

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Scenery:

- We have an eventhub trigger function coded using python 3.x .
- All resources are connected using VNET integration. (All resources under
  the same subnet)
- We are using User Assign Managed Identity to allow
  access to resources.
- Azure Function with ASP Premium Plan EventHub Standard with 32 partitions

[CPU utilization details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQtYz.png)

---

---

We are facing a weird behavior.
After some time that function is running, we are expecting the function to scale out based on metrics that we had configured, like cpu avg. But we realized that we still have some instances idle and function don't get that instance host to use to execute it's code.

Following the MS documentation to *[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host#partition-ownership-tracking:~:text=976-,Here,-%2C%20each%20host%20acquires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host#partition-ownership-tracking:%7E:text=976-,Here,-%2C%20each%20host%20acquires)* we can see that if you have a eventhub configured with 32 partitions your Azure Function will scale out to max possible Hosts Instances in order to attend the load that came from eventhub. But in our case the Azure function does not scale out, and even with we have 10 hosts already the function use just 2 hosts, for exemple. If we look at the metrics and split the chart by instances we can see the behavior with 2 hosts using 100% of you CPU and the others unused.

After investigating a bit we realized checking function's storage account that have just two **ownership** created even we having one eventhub with 32 partitions and more 3 hosts instances warmed and idle.
The problem is solved when function is restarted.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already updated the post adding more info. But resuming we have an azure function using eventhub trigger that doesn't use all hosts to processing the messages.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT can you look at now?

Comment: I understand that on certain host instances - high CPU is utilizing by the function trigger and other instances are not being used - is this correct @MagnoOliveira!

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of instance details on cpu utilization?

Comment: Sure. I added on post.

Answer (score 0):

If the scale controller determines that the instance(s) currently handling the events are unable to handle the load, regardless of pre-warmed or minimum instances, **Premium hosting plan Azure Functions** will use the other instances.

So, even if you have 5 in pre-warmed and minimum, it will begin sending all events to one instance and then load balance to the others once that one becomes overburdened.

This is how the **scale controller** balances the load.

When looking at the CPU utilization, the average CPU utilization remains at 67% & 57% respectively, only when they exceed 70% and remain for a period of time will events be routed to utilize other instances.

Comment: Is the behavior the same even using Elastic Premium instead of ASP Premium?

Comment: Hello @MagnoOliveira, Scale Controller is available in Consumption & Elastic Premium plans, not in the App Service premium plan.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly. What is the expected behavior using ASP Premium in this scenario?

Comment: Hello @MagnoOliveira, Scaling in in our control completely in the dedicated plan Azure Function App which you can use manual scaling or autoscaling configuration. Suppose if you configured to run the function app in 2 instances, the application will be running in 2 instances all the time, irrespective of the incoming cpu/memory or load utilization.